# Name for metric space where every ball contains only finitely many points?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, terminology, integer-lattices

Is there a word/standard terminology for when every ball $B_r$ (of finite radius $r < \infty$) in a metric space contains only finitely many points of that space?

Specifically: I am thinking about the case where $X$ is a metric space, and I have a subset $Y \subset X$ and I want to say that any ball $B_r = \{ x \in X : || x || < r\}$ contains only finitely many points of $Y$. (This is meant to generalize the analogous property for lattices such as $\mathbb Z^n \subset \mathbb R^n$.)

Comment: do you allow the ball to contain $0$ points ?

Comment: @zwim sure 0 points is allowed.

Comment: @Karl - I don't think so (unless I've misstated something). For instance the lattice $Z^n$ satisfies this property and is not finite.

Comment: Oops, right, I was considering only totally bounded metric spaces.

Comment: This seems close to but stronger than locally finite

Comment: Locally finite proper metric space.

Comment: Such space is necessary discrete and at most countable btw. And every discrete countable space is metrizable in such way.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah neat, so *proper* makes the ball $B_r$ (or the closure of it anyway) compact, then I can cover all the points of $Y$ in the ball with open neighbourhoods $U_i$. Each $U_i$ contains only finitely many points of $Y$ thanks to the *locally finite* condition. I get a finite subset of those $U_i$ that still covers $B_r$ using the compactness and so end up with finitely many $U_i$ each containing finitely many points.

Comment: @freakish: why must the space be countable?

Comment: @RobArthan write the space as a countable union of finite balls of increasing radius around a point

Comment: $Y$ must not only be discrete, it must also be complete. A discrete space can have Cauchy sequences with non-constant tails if it is incomplete. But such a Cauchy sequence would also require an infinite number of points within some ball. So under your condition, $Y$ cannot have a Cauchy sequence that isn't eventually constant. Thus all Cauchy sequences in $Y$ converge.